# foreign keys are not being created

Tags: mysql, sql, database

> **Question:**
>
> Want to perform a Select Query below (must be this query):
>
> SELECT QuestionId FROM Question WHERE (QuestionNo = ? AND SessionId =
>   ?)
>
> In order to be able to find the QuestionId's in the Question table and
>   store it in the Answer Table for all the answers so that we can
>   determine which answers belong to which question

**Problem:**

The problem with the mysqli code is that it is not able to insert the correct QuestionId value. It keeps displaying 0 for QuestionId in the `Answer` Table. So can somebody fix this in order to be able to be able to display the correct QuestionId?

It has to be done the SELECT query provided at top. I have to use that in mysqli.

Here are the db tables:

Question Table

```
QuestionId (auto)  SessionId  QuestionNo
4                  2          1
5                  2          2
6                  2          3
```

Answer Table at moment:

```
AnswerId (auto)  QuestionId  Answer
7                0           A
8                0           C
9                0           A
10               0           B
11               0           True
```

What Answer Table should look like:

```
AnswerId (auto)  QuestionId  Answer
7                4           A
8                4           C
9                5           A
10               5           B
11               6           True
```

Below is the code:

```
 $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionNo) 
    VALUES (?, ?)";
if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($questionsql)) {
    // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
}

 $answersql = "INSERT INTO Answer (QuestionId, Answer) 
    VALUES (?, ?)";
if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
    // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
}



//make sure both prepared statements succeeded before proceeding
if( $insert && $insertanswer)
{
    $sessid =  $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '');
    $c = count($_POST['numQuestion']);

    for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ )
    {


            $insert->bind_param("ii", $sessionid, $_POST['numQuestion'][$i]);

            $insert->execute();

            if ($insert->errno) 
            {
                // Handle query error here
                echo __LINE__.': '.$insert->error;
                break 1;
            }
}

        $results = $_POST['value'];
        foreach($results as $id => $value) 
        {
            $answer = $value;

            $lastID = $id;

            $questionidquery = "SELECT QuestionId FROM Question WHERE (QuestionNo = ? AND SessionId = ?)";

        if (!$questionidstmt = $mysqli->prepare($questionidquery)) {
        // Handle errors with prepare operation here
          echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
        }


        // Bind parameter for statement
        $questionidstmt->bind_param("ii", $lastID, $sessionId);

        // Execute the statement
        $questionidstmt->execute();

                    if ($questionidstmt->errno) 
                    {
                        // Handle query error here
                        echo __LINE__.': '.$questionidstmt->error;
                        break 2;
                    }

        // This is what matters. With MySQLi you have to bind result fields to
        // variables before calling fetch()
        $questionidstmt->bind_result($quesid);

        // This populates $optionid
        $questionidstmt->fetch(); 

        $questionidstmt->close(); 



            foreach($value as $answer) 
            {
                $insertanswer->bind_param("is", $quesid, $answer);

                $insertanswer->execute();

                if ($insertanswer->errno) {
                    // Handle query error here
                    echo __LINE__.': '.$insertanswer->error;
                    break 3;
                }
            }
        }


    //close your statements at the end


    $insertanswer->close();
    $insert->close();
}

?>
```

Comment: What database are you using? What errors are you getting?

Comment: What do you mean by "they're not being created"?

Comment: Are you sure your creating the FOREIGN KEY on the right database and not a test or development database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the last value of the sequence used as the autoincrementing id in Question directly after the INSERT - do this using the LAST_INSERT_ID() SQL function. You can then use this value as a parameter when you insert into Answer.

[This is an article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-sequences.htm) on how this may be done.

You can also restructure your code by eliminating the query for the question id in the insert-answer loop. Instead, when you insert the questions, fill an associative array with the QuestionId for each QuestionNo. While looping over the answers, use the associative array to quickly retrieve the QuestionId. Memory should not be a concert as you currently have all questions and answers in the HTTP request.

The core of the code will then look like:

```
// AA: Declare an empty associative array for QuestionNo -> QuestionID
$question_ids = array()

for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ )
{
        // AA: Extract the QuestionNo for multiple use
        $questionNo = $_POST['numQuestion'][$i];

        $insert->bind_param("ii", $sessionid, $questionNo);

        $insert->execute();

        if ($insert->errno)
        {
            // Handle query error here
            echo __LINE__.': '.$insert->error;
            break 1;
        }

        // AA: Retrieve the questionId from MySQL
        $questionId = mysql_insert_id();

        // AA: Add a key-value pair (QuestionNo, QuestionId) to $question_ids
        $question_ids[$questionNo] = $questionId;
}

$results = $_POST['value'];
foreach($results as $id => $value)
{
    $answer = $value;

    // AA: Look up the QuestionId for the question number
    $quesid = $question_ids[$id];

    foreach($value as $answer)
    {
        $insertanswer->bind_param("is", $quesid, $answer);

        $insertanswer->execute();

        if ($insertanswer->errno) {
            // Handle query error here
            echo __LINE__.': '.$insertanswer->error;
            break 3;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: I'm not a PHP programmer, and I haven't tested this, so there may be syntax errors. Sorry :(

Comment: I need to be able to do it with the select query provided. My problem is knowing where to place the code. If you can show me where I need to place the code using the LAST_INSERT_ID() then that would be great. I have tried this before by the way but I was having big trouble with it. Please if you have time show me where I should place the code because that is the big problem I am having

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked fine, it will let me award bounty to you in 20 hours which I will give you by then :)